# How to correctly unbind dom-elements in jQuery widgets?

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks, unbind

I have some troubles with memory leaks in JavaScript.

I'm using the [Leak Memory 0.4.5 extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/2490/) which shows me those JavaScript objects which still remain in the memory.

Now I'm not sure how to correctly unbind dom-object from events etc.

For instance, I have a jQuery-widget called 'dropdownbox'.
In the destroy method I make all the necessary stuff to unbind event-handlers like:

```
this.box.find('.toggler').unbind();
this.box.remove();
this.box = null;
```

These 3 lines are a must, or is it possible to call only this.box.remove()?

Till today I never have unbound or cleared something from DOM elements because I thought it doesn't matter. But I came up with the problem, that after 2 hours of developing on the same site, my Firefox consumes 1GB!

So I read a bit of memory leaks when using closures etc.
So that's my second question: I use very often closures because they are really cool and handy.
Some people say that you shouldn't use closures for everything. so for example if we have the following code:

```
function foo(param1, param2) {
  var local1, local2;
  $('a').click(function() {
    alert('YEAH');
  });
}
```

It would be better to do it like:

```
funtion foo(param1, param2) {
      var local1, local2;
      $('a').click(clickEvent);
    }
function() {
  alert('YEAH');
}
```

Or have I misunderstood that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call:

```
this.box.remove();
this.box = null;
```

[`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) will also [remove any child elements and their event handlers/data as well](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/manipulation.js#L156).  Nulling out the reference held by `.box` to the element is the last step for complete removal (assuming nothing *else* it hanging onto it).

For your other example, the second version is a bit more efficient since the handler's not copied all over the place, the bigger that handler is the more it makes a difference.

Comment: ok so i have to call $(window).unload(function() {
$('temp').mywidget('destroy') }); to clean all correctly?

Comment: @Davincho - You can, though most garbage collectors will cleanup when leaving the page (older IE you need to check but that's it). It's important to cleanup everything possible in your `destroy` function though, so any manual destroys are complete.

Comment: that's the point: the garbage collector won't cleanup an object when we have circular references, so is there other posibility than call the destroy-method when the pages get unloaded?

Comment: @Davincho - What circular references do you have? Event handlers and data aren't referenced by the DOM element, only it's `$.expando` property is there, not a direct reference, just a unique ID.  If you can, you want to avoid creating circular references at all, like the jQuery event system does by default.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old topic, but You have mentioned closures yet the examples you have provided are not closures. Closure "happens" when **a function returns the inner function**. People will probably look here because this question is on top of google search results for "javascript memory leaks unbind events" and they should not be given the wrong information :) I know it was not intentional.

Please look here for an excellent closures explanation: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)